# Remove parameter from array then put back into array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to remove a parameter within an array, change the value, then put it back into the array.

This is how I'm initially getting the values:

```
<?php
  $value = $_POST['criteria'];

  $valueSet = isset($value['countries']) ? $value['countries'] : '';
  $valueSplit= explode(",", $valueSet);
  $valueFinal = "'". implode("','", $valueSplit) . "'";

  echo $valueFinal;
?>
```

Using the above, the `$valueFinal` variable can look like this:

```
'USA','CAN','FRA'
```

I need to be able to check if 'FRA' exists in the array, remove it from the array, change it to 'GER', then put it back into the array.

In the end, the `$valueFinal` array should look like this:

```
'USA','CAN','GER'
```

I am not sure if this is possible. How can I make this work?

### Edit

I am able to use the following to check if the value exists:

```
if(in_array("FRA", $valueSplit)
```

But I am not sure how to update that single value, then add it back to the array.

Comment: Why even go to an array? `str_replace("'FRA'", "'GER'", "'USA','CAN','FRA'");` or if you need to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: Why are you wrapping each value in single quotes, @JohnB?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5179606/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to remove and put back an array element. You simply find the position of the element, and replace it by assigning to the same index.

Use `array_search()` to find the index of the old string in the array. If it finds it, reassign the element.

```
$index = array_search('FRA', $valueSplit);
if ($index !== false) {
    $valueSplit[$index] = 'GER';
}
```

Make sure you use `!==` rather than `!=`, since `0` is a valid index and it compares equal to `false` with type juggling.

Comment: Satisfy my curiosity: Which part of this is not obvious?

Comment: Please forgive my lack of knowledge.  I have never done anything like this before.  I was able to use in_array to check if the value exists.  But I was not sure how to update the actual value and/or place it back into the array.

Comment: Any tutorial on PHP arrays should mention `array_search()`.

Comment: @mickmackusa All the mega-dupes are about removing, but the question is about replacing. I admit that they're similar, but I didn't have either of these in my list of common dupes.

Comment: Okay, I changed to a better dupe.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks, I've saved both dupes for the future